# How to change href url upon change of a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code

```
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>$id</td>
  <td>
    <div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-sm-10'>
      <select id='form-control' class='form-control' onchange='leaveChange()'>
        <option value='$prices'>price</option>
        <option value='$Sale'>Sale</option>
        <option value='$payment'>payment</option>
      </select>";
      ?>    
      <script>
      function leaveChange() {
        if (document.getElementById("form-control").value == ""){
          document.getElementById("enableordisable").innerHTML = "Enable";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Disabled";
        }     
        if(document.getElementById("form-control").value == 1){
          document.getElementById("enableordisable").innerHTML = "Disable";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Enabled";
        }        
      }
      </script>
  <?php echo "</div></td>
  <td><p id='status'>---</p></td>
  <td> <a id='enableordisable' type='addToTable' class='btn waves- effect waves-light btn-custom' href='function/enabledisable.php?stuff=$id&price=$price'>price</a></td>
```

What I want to do is when a value is selected from the dropdown, I want this href URL in the button

```
href='function/enabledisable.php?stuff=$id&price=$price&item'
```

to be updated so that item will point to the option chosen from the dropdown.
How can I do this?
Any help will be appreciated!

**note: I cannot use the value inside of the options**

Comment: trigger the value of the href to change by a the dropdown change event.  Create the event and invoke it to modify the value.

Comment: I would recommend to put a first option in your dropdown like this, `<option value='0'>Select here...</option>` if you want to trigger your function if the first option is selected in the first selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you wish...

It get the `text` of the selected option as the data to be added after `&item=`.
Notice that I fixed your HTML a little to make it work.
See comments in code.

```js
// Pass the base href to JS
var baseHref = "function/enabledisable.php?stuff=$id&price=$price";

// On change event function
function leaveChange(el) {
  if (document.getElementById("form-control").value == ""){
    document.getElementById("enableordisable").innerHTML = "Enable";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Disabled";
  }     
  if(document.getElementById("form-control").value == 1){
    document.getElementById("enableordisable").innerHTML = "Disable";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Enabled";
  }

  // Set the additional GET data to the URL
  var index = el.selectedIndex;
  var newHref = baseHref+"&item="+el.getElementsByTagName("option")[index].text
  console.log(newHref);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$id</td>
      <td>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <div class='col-sm-10'>
            <select id='form-control' class='form-control' onchange='leaveChange(this)'>
              <option value='$prices'>price</option>
              <option value='$Sale'>Sale</option>
              <option value='$payment'>payment</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><p id='status'>---</p></td>
      <td> <a id='enableordisable' type='addToTable' class='btn waves- effect waves-light btn-custom' href='function/enabledisable.php?stuff=$id&price=$price'>price</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I assume that `$id` and `$price` are PHP variables.

Comment: thank you so much man! THIS WORKED i cant thank you enough, really appreciate the help :P

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("enableordisable").href = 'function/enabledisable.php?stuff=$id&price=$price&item';
```

this can change the URL of a `<a>`